CGDB ouputs garbled string using 'set dis'
I just installed the latest version of CGDB on Ubuntu 20.04.3.
Code is displayed normally at first:

However, it prints chaotic characters like '^[[01;34...' after using :set dis

How can I fix it?
Thanks.
I've tried setting TERM to xterm-256color but it doesn't work.
